# determining equality for empty strings parsed with javascript String.fromCharCode()

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

The char code for `""` is `\u0000`.

```
String.fromCharCode("\u0000"); //=> ""
```

However, for some reason, in javascript this parses to be a string that is not equal to `""`.

```
String.fromCharCode("\u0000") == ""; //=> false
String.fromCharCode("\u0000") === ""; //=> false
```

So if you can't use `==` or `===`, how do you determine equality for parsed empty strings and actual empty strings?

Comment: `fromCharCode` takes a `Number`, e.g. `String.fromCharCode(32) === ' '`. Also, \u0000 is nil.

Comment: I think you already know that \u0000 is nil, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

`String.fromCharCode("\u0000")` does not return an empty string. You can see this with `String.fromCharCode("\u0000").length`, which returns `1`, not `0` like `"".length`.

It returns a string with 1 character in it, whose code is `0`. This character doesn't print as anything, so the string appears to be empty, but it isn't; it contains an invisible character. That's why it's not equal to `""`.